# Is it even possible to migrate huge SQL Server relational database to Azure replicating across multi-regions with master-master replication?

Tags: sql-server, azure, devops, geo-replication, azure-sql

I have my DB users who frequently performs write operations from both China and US, Currently we have data on premise in the US region and are facing huge challenges as write and read operations are very slow for all users across the world having most write Operations from 3 regions. So, I am looking to keep master nodes in US and China and have other read region replicas spread across world. I need someone to help me with this approach if possible or not?

I will be fine with creating my own infrastructure, own virtual machines, own private subnets across regions, own SQL Server instances in different regions, but looking for possible resource if it is even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is far too broad and not really on-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider about [geo-replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-configure-portal) in Azure sql. It provides multi-region read and write and synchronization of primary and secondary nodes. But you may use [Data Sync Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-agent-overview) to synchronize databases between Azure China and Azure Global.

Comment: Hi @Joseph, As far as i see multi-region read is available in azure sql geo-replication but not multi-region write except for one primary node. You mean Data Sync agent helps us in geo replication of master-master nodes in Azure sql?

Comment: As far as I know, azure sql geo-replicationt support multi-region write, we can use it to help disperse the pressure of reading and writing. It may be difficult to sync databases in China.